# Apply rank using RowNumber based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, case-statement, row-number

Looking for some suggestions here on a project that I am currently working on.
I have a table that consists of 

**Vehicle Name**

**Number of Contracts**

**Sale Amount**

**Ratio**

I would like to add a Row Number to the table based on certain criteria.

1. IF there are 5 or more Vehicles where **Ratio** = 0 then RowNumber() OVER Order By **Sale Amount** but only apply the row number where **Ratio** = 0 
   "everything else" RowNumber() OVER Order By **Ratio**  
   I would like the row number to continue not start all over when applying the Row Number to the "everything else". So if the condition is met apply RowNumber where **Ratio** = 0 using **Sale Amount**. Sort the rest based on **Ratio**. Row numbers must be continuous and not start over.

   if the above condition fails then just use RowNumber() Over Order By **Ratio**

What I am basically trying to do here is add a second condition for ranking if the first one fails. So if condition 1 fails then rank on second condition.

I would paste a table but just realized how complicated getting a table in here is. Sorry!

Here is an example of something I was trying but did not work. It kept applying the row number using Ratio no matter if the case statement is true.

```
Select 
,ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER 
(ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN RATIO = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 5
          THEN Sale_Amount 
          ELSE Ratio END) ASC
    )as Rows1
FROM Table
```

Not Sure if RowNumber() is the best in this situation.

Any answers or tips would be helpful! Thanks in advance!

Here is an attempt of showing my data:

Original Data Set:

```
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------+  
| Vehicle | # of Contracts | Sale Amount | Ratio  |  
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------+  
| A       |              1 | $800        | 0.00%  |  
| B       |              1 | $800        | 0.00%  |  
| C       |              1 | $978        | 0.00%  |  
| D       |              4 | $2,069      | 0.00%  |  
| E       |              2 | $1,600      | 0.00%  |  
| F       |              6 | $4,210      | 0.00%  |  
| G       |              3 | $1,289      | 0.00%  |  
| H       |              5 | $1,590      | 0.00%  |  
| I       |             10 | $8,456      | 13.45% |  
| J       |             12 | $9,000      | 10.56% |  
| K       |              6 | $2,458      | 20.00% |  
| L       |              9 | $3,607      | 34.50% |  
| M       |             10 | $7,987      | 70.80% |  
| N       |              2 | $954        | 96.89% |  
| O       |              2 | $800        | 34.67% |  
| P       |              3 | $800        | 23.09% |  
| Q       |              5 | $901        | 12.78% |  
| R       |              7 | $1,008      | 45.78% |  
| T       |              9 | $765        | 20.00% |  
| U       |              2 | $345        | 1.00%  |  
| V       |              4 | $834        | 45.00% |  
+---------+----------------+-------------+--------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+-----------+---------+----------------+-------------+--------+  
| RowNumber | Vehicle | # of Contracts | Sale Amount | Ratio  |  
+-----------+---------+----------------+-------------+--------+  
|         1 | F       |              6 | $4,210      | 0.00%  |  
|         2 | H       |              5 | $1,590      | 0.00%  |  
|         3 | D       |              4 | $2,069      | 0.00%  |  
|         4 | G       |              3 | $1,289      | 0.00%  |  
|         5 | E       |              2 | $1,600      | 0.00%  |  
|         6 | A       |              1 | $800        | 0.00%  |  
|         7 | B       |              1 | $800        | 0.00%  |  
|         8 | C       |              1 | $978        | 0.00%  |  
|         9 | U       |              2 | $345        | 1.00%  |  
|        10 | J       |             12 | $9,000      | 10.56% |  
|        11 | Q       |              5 | $901        | 12.78% |  
|        12 | I       |             10 | $8,456      | 13.45% |  
|        13 | K       |              6 | $2,458      | 20.00% |  
|        14 | T       |              9 | $765        | 20.00% |  
|        15 | P       |              3 | $800        | 23.09% |  
|        16 | L       |              9 | $3,607      | 34.50% |  
|        17 | O       |              2 | $800        | 34.67% |  
|        18 | V       |              4 | $834        | 45.00% |  
|        19 | R       |              7 | $1,008      | 45.78% |  
|        20 | M       |             10 | $7,987      | 70.80% |  
|        21 | N       |              2 | $954        | 96.89% |  
+-----------+---------+----------------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result. You can create one in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6)

Comment: Thanks! I went to the site but it didnt load. I was trying to use senseful solutions but when I pasted the table in it came out very weird.

Comment: Paste it anyway, let us edit them.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @johnsaunders - thank you for the clarification. This is my first question and will be sure to not make that mistake in the future

Comment: Your result does not order by `Sale Amount`,  instead it's ordering by `# of Contracts DESC', for the first criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM OVER()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`

*Based on your result, I order the first criteria by # of Contracts DESC*.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/339d3/1/0)

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        ZeroRatio = SUM(CASE WHEN Ratio = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER()
    FROM TestData
),
CteRN AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN ZeroRatio >= 5 AND Ratio = 0 THEN NumContracts END DESC,
            Ratio
        )
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    RN, Vehicle, NumContracts, SaleAmount, Ratio
FROM CteRN
ORDER BY RN
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!!! I did not use the Sum OVER() - for some reason my query was running so slow when I added this. It looks like I was close but in the case statement i was missing "Ratio = 0". You saved me a bunch of time! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your example output follows what you said you're after, so may need to adjust the `ORDER BY` fields, but this is what I think you're after:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Ratio) AS Ratio_CT 
              FROM Table1
              )
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN Ratio_CT >= 5 AND Ratio = 0 THEN [Sale Amount] END DESC,Ratio) AS Rows1
FROM cte
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c83a/11/0)